# ajax function updates on first call only

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp MVC 4 along with Jquery 1.10.2

I am trying to update a table within a partial view and debugging Javascript seems to be akin to Voodoo (at least to me any way).

On the first call to my ajax function the update takes place as expected. Any subsequent calls are not registered.

I have read several articles and stackoverflow answers, which included setting `cache = false`, reading the network tab in developer tools to get some idea of what is happening.

From the second suggestion I can see that the fist call returns a `200` status response, but the second call seems to do nothing.

I have put alert boxes in the script, on the first call, all are displayed and data updates, but on the second call nothing happens, Why?

the script

```
$("#resultsPerPage").change(function () {
    alert("pre")
    var selectedText = parseInt($(this).find(":selected").text())
    call_PropertyTable("", 1, selectedText);
    alert("post")
})

    //calls _PropertyTable Partial view
function call_PropertyTable(param, val, resultsPerPage) {
    $("#hdnCurrentPage").text(val);
    alert("pre-ajax")
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "_PropertyTable",
        type: "get",
        data: { 'param': param, 'value': val, 'resultsPerPage': resultsPerPage },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#properties").html(data);
        }
    });
    alert("post-ajax")
}
```

the view

```
<div id="properties">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PropertyTable", Model);}
</div>
```

the partial view

```
//^^^other data not updating after first ajax call^^^
<select id="resultsPerPage" name="dataTables-example_length" aria-controls="dataTables-example" class="form-control input-sm">
                <option value="10" @{if (ViewBag.PageRange == 10) { ViewBag.Selected = "selected"; } else { ViewBag.Selected = ""; }} @ViewBag.Selected>10</option>
                <option value="25" @{if (ViewBag.PageRange == 25) { ViewBag.Selected = "selected"; } else { ViewBag.Selected = ""; }} @ViewBag.Selected>25</option>
                <option value="50" @{if (ViewBag.PageRange == 50) { ViewBag.Selected = "selected"; } else { ViewBag.Selected = ""; }} @ViewBag.Selected>50</option>
            </select> records per page
```

the controller

```
    public ActionResult _PropertyTable(string param, int value = 1, int resultsPerPage = 10)
    {
        ViewBag.PageRange = resultsPerPage;
        //other stuff
        return PartialView(properties);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is replacing the `<select>` element with `id="resultsPerPage"` so the original `<select>` element that you attached the handler to no longer exists and therefore the event is never called. You need to use event delegation using the `.on()` function.

Replace

```
$("#resultsPerPage").change(function () {
  ....
});
```

with

```
$('#properties').on('change', '#resultsPerPage', function(){
  .....
});
```

Edit

A few suggestions to improve your code. Not clear why you have a separate `call_PropertyTable()` function so I have just combined these for simplicity.

```
var properties = $('#properties'); // cache elements your repeatedly refer to
properties.on('change', '#resultsPerPage', function() {
  var selectedText = $(this).val(); // all that's required
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: '@Url.Action("_PropertyTable")', // don't hard code your url's
    type: "get",
    data: { param: '', value: 1, resultsPerPage: selectedText}, // no need to quote property names
    success: function (data) {
      properties.html(data);
    }
});
```

Or more simply using the $.get() shortcut

```
$.get('@Url.Action("_PropertyTable")', { param: '', value: 1, resultsPerPage: selectedText}, function(data) {
  properties.html(data);
});
```

Instead of manually creating your markup, use a view model and strongly bind to you model properties using the html helpers

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
  public int PageRange { get; set; }
  public SelectList PageRangeList { get; set; }
  ....
}

public ActionResult _PropertyTable(string param, int value = 1, int resultsPerPage = 10)
{
  IEnumerable<int> pageRanges = new List<int>{ 10, 25, 50 };
  SampleViewModel model = new SampleViewModel()
  {
    PageRange = resultsPerPage,
    PageRangeList = new SelectList(pageRanges),
    ....
  };
  return PartialView(model);
}
```

and in the partial view use

```
@model SampleViewModel
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PageRange, Model.PageRangeList)
```

Note its unclear why you need to generate the dropdownlist in the partial view as opposed to having it in the main view (outside the `<div id="properties">` element) so that it is not replaced with exactly the html that it originally was (and therefore use of event delegation would not be necessary).

Comment: That worked, thank you. Just re-read the docs, that would have never made sense to me. I now understand....i think

Comment: @tony09uk, A lot of your other code is not ideal. No time now, but I will update the answer later with some additional suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. I know I have a long way to go and any advice is greatly appriciated

Comment: See edit for a few suggestions to improve your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I certainly see your point based on the code I have posted and will add the page range to my view model. Just wish I could post bigger chunks to get more feedback. But thank you for your help